# Redirect every page except frontpage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all pages to a new website with the same site structure, e.g. olddomain.com/123.html to newdomain.com/123.html, this works perfectly fine with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

But i want the Frontpage to be redirected to newdomain.com/landingpage, i tried the following and it isn't working.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.com/landingpage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 #redirect homepage to a specific location on new domain
 RewriteRule ^/?$ https://newdomain.com/landingpage [L,R=301]
 #redirect everything else from old domain to new
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```